# Fb Pixel Tags firing in Preview Mode but not in LIVE mode

Tags: google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

I have been deploying a Fb pixel via Tag Manager. No matter how I set it up, everything works like a charm when in Preview Mode, but the pixel doesn't fire when in LIVE mode (I am using Facebook Pixel Helper chrome extension to check).
In fact I can only see just my interactions in the Events manager of facebook.

What can it be?

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason for this might occur due to permission status.

If you do not have publish permission on the container, you might be just creating a version instead of going live.